# About requirements of array in frama-c

Tags: frama-c

When writing ACSL of function in frama-c, I want the array of global variables to satisfy a requirement, for example:

```
int a[5];

/*@requires \forall int i; 0 <= i <= 4 ==> a[i] > 0;
*/
void f()
{
    do something with a...;
}
```

I want all the elements of a larger than 0, so is that right? I try that, that doesn't work, can anyone tell me how to write it?

Thanks very much.

Comment: What do you mean by "that doesn't work" ?

Comment: Your question should contain a commandline, a Frama-C version and an exact copy of the message you obtained that makes you think that it “doesn't work”.

Comment: Actually, your question should contain a C program that can be passed to Frama-C. Your example would be rejected because `do something with a...;` is not valid C syntax.

Comment: sorry, maybe I didn't express my question well, "that doesn't work" means "requires \forall int i; 0 <= i <= 4 ==> a[i] > 0;" doesn't work, in function f, the value range of a's element is [--,--], not [1, INT_MAX]. and what I expect is [1, INT_MAX]

Comment: and what I want to know is how to write ACSL, thanks again

Comment: @user3568607 you should edit your question with what you have put in the comment, and say explicitely that your are using the `Value` plugin of Frama-C.

Answer (score 2):

As explained in its [manual](http://frama-c.com/download/frama-c-value-analysis.pdf), the Value Analysis plug-in understands only a subset of ACSL formulas.

In particular, it does not handle quantifiers, thus your pre-condition has no effect on the resulting state. The usual trick is to
write a wrapper function that will call `f` in an appropriate environment. For that, you can in particular use the `Frama_C_interval` function. For instance, your wrapper could be (don't forget to `#include <limits.h>` in your file because of `INT_MAX`)

```
void wrap() {
  for(int i=0; i<=4; i++) a[i] = Frama_C_interval(1,INT_MAX);
  f();
}
```

and you would call Frama-C this way:

```
frama-c -val -main wrap -lib-entry file.c
```